# Celery Task Fails with "Object Does Not Exist" Error Despite Using Auto-Commit in Django

Tags: django, celery

In my Django application, I've encountered a rare issue where a Celery task, invoked via apply_async immediately after creating an object in a model's save method, failed because it could not find the newly created object. This issue has occurred only once, making it particularly puzzling given Django's auto-commit mode, which should commit the new object to the database immediately. Below is a simplified version of the code where the issue appeared:

from django.db import models
from myapp.tasks import process_new_object

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     ....

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
     ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_obj = MyModel.objects.create(name="Newly Created Object")
        process_new_object.apply_async(args=[new_obj.pk], countdown=5)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)




@shared_task
def process_new_object(obj_id):
    try:
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj_id)
        ...
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

what might be potential causes for the Celery task to sometimes fail to find the newly created object, despite the delay and Django's auto-commit?